# Curl - How do I catch a empty response

Tags: curl, lua

cURL seem not to call the writefuntion when empty response returned
On a empty response the responseHandler does not get called.
How then do I catch an empty response?

```
 local cURL = require("cURL")

  function responseHandler(data)
        print(data)
  end

  local headers = {
    "Accept: text/*",
    "Accept-Language: en",
    "Accept-Charset: iso-8859-1,*,utf-8",
    "Cache-Control: no-cache"
  }

  local url = 'http://mydomain/path'

  c = cURL.easy{
    url            = url
    ssl_verifypeer = false,
    ssl_verifyhost = false,
    httpheader     = headers,
    writefunction  = function(data)
        responseHandler(data)
    end
  }

  c:perform()
```

Comment: Which curl library are you using? I see there is luacurl and lua-curl, which are different.

Comment: Also, can you be more specific as to what you are trying to do? It looks like the writeFunction is only called if there is data. So, if there's no data, it never gets called. Is it that you need to know when the request is complete? If so, there are other mechanisms to do that.

Comment: Yes to know when request is complete. If there is no data that means there was a problem on the remote site so I want to set some error handling.

Comment: Or another way to look at it. How to get the data length?